Which user account’s authorizations are used by a calendar sync function?
I think the title is self-explanatory, but here are some options I can think of:

the account of the calendar owner
The account of the user who created the calendar event


The title is not self-explanatory. It is unclear what type of calendar sync you are referring to. The tags include [google-apps-script], which implies that you have written code that syncs calendars. Please [edit] the question and add all relevant detail there. If you want to show code, see How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

When Apps Script code is run interactively (on demand), it runs under the account of the user at the keyboard. At the first execution of a script project, the user is asked to authorize access to the Google Services used by the code. Types of interactive execution include running the code through an add-on, a button, or a custom menu item.
When an Apps Script function is executed by an installable trigger, it runs under the account that originally created the trigger. That account needs to authorize the script project when creating the trigger if that account has not already authorized it.
Web apps can be deployed to run under the account of the user who created the web app, or under the account of the user at the keyboard. That party needs to authorize the code during deployment or first execution.
Simple triggers are available when the script project is bound to a document, such as a Google Sheets, Docs, Slides, or Forms file. These triggers run in a context where they cannot access any personal information nor call services that require authorization. For example, all email and calendar methods require authorization, so they cannot be called from a simple trigger and will throw errors. When no such methods are used, the code runs under the account of the user at the keyboard, but cannot access that user's personal information. The same applies to Google Sheets custom functions.
